# IIS Url Rewriting IP Address

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iis

Is it possible to rewrite an IP adress to a name? For example I have `http://159.163.21.22/Default.aspx` and want to change it to `http://example/Default.aspx`.

Thank you guys!

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not very experienced with URL Rewrites but my common sense says that it shouldn't be possible, people would be able to use whatever they want as domain. I think the rewrite mods only work on the part after the domain

Comment: Can you use HOSTS file or DNS Server ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you can change your host file so any http://example/default.aspx page will go to http://159.163.21.22/ which is where you site is. Its good for when you are using API keys and have to test locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`example` wont resolve unless there is a DNS entry in your local table (hosts file) or on your local DNS server because it's not a fully qualified domain name so you'd need to set that first.  Once that's set you could use the URL rewrite example above, but note that it does a 301 (temporary) redirect, so browsers and search engines aren't going to update their index which may hurt you from an SEO perspective and may add additional load to your DNS servers.

If you're looking for a way to do a URL rewrite without a 301/302 redirect, you're out of luck.  The best alternative would be to go buy a domain name and register it and start using that name instead of the IP.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Micosoft URL Rewrite. you can get that from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7435).

First install URL rewrite then modify your web.config with following entry

```
<system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="IP Hit" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="159.163.21.22" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Change www.yoursite.com as per your requirement

Comment: No, I mean is changing IP to my own set name exmaple mysite/default.aspx not www.mysite.com/default.aspx